# When I do "git svn rebase" it fetches the svn author names instead of the git author names

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I have used `git svn clone -A authors.txt ...` to clone an svn repository.
My `authors.txt` had entries like this:

```
svnid = Firstname Lastname <Firstname.Lastname@example.com>
```

That worked fine and in `git log` the authors look like:

```
Author: Firstname Lastname <firstname.lastname@example.com>
```

Now when I do `git svn rebase -A authors.txt` the authors for the new entries look like this:

```
Author: svnid <svnid@12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789abc>
```

I used the accepted answer from  "[Retroactively Correct Authors with Git SVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392332/retroactively-correct-authors-with-git-svn)"
  to fix it, but after the next `git svn rebase -A authors.txt` the authors are destroyed again.

What can I do to preserve the proper author names?

**EDIT:** I'm using git version 1.7.6.msysgit.0
on Windows obviously.

Comment: Strange. I have the `svn.authorsfile` set in the repository and not only it always uses it (I never pass -A to rebase), but it even fails if a svn username is not there and I have to fill it in before it continues.

Comment: That's how it's supposed to work according to the manpage. I also tried to set `git config svn.authorsfile authors.txt`, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Perhaps it's time to ask on the project mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

`svn.authorsfile` is a bit of artistic license (aka bug). If you open .git/config file in `$EDITOR` you will see something like:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
url = https://crosswire.org/svn/sword
fetch = trunk:refs/remotes/trunk
branches = branches/*:refs/remotes/*
tags = tags/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
```

add the line

```
authorsfile = .git/svn/authors.txt
```

as the last line of that section (and put your `authors.txt` file to `.git/svn/` directory, of course).