# Adding SVN author file to git repo after a conversion and commit with git-svn

Tags: git, git-svn

I recently switched over to using git and followed [these instructions](http://help.github.com/import-from-subversion/%20%22these%20instructions) to convert my SVN repository. However, I failed to follow the instructions to make the authors file, and I have already committed my converted repository and have been working on it, adding further commits.

My old SVN repo is now outdated, but I would like to do get the author names to match up now, I already created the authors file. How can I do so without messing up my most recent commit history?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392332/retroactively-correct-authors-with-git-svn) if you want to rewrite your local git history, maybe you can alter it to get the authors from your author file instead of from the script.

Comment: I followed the suggestions there and it seemed to have worked, but how do you then go and push the edited/corrected authors back to the remote?