# git filter-branch duplicated commits

Tags: git, branch, commit, git-filter-branch

I was rewriting my git repository's author history like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/392356/1732520), however my original structure turned from

```
D (user 2) <-- master
|
C (user 2)                E (user 1) <-- branch 1
|                         |
+-------------------------+
|
B (user 1)
|
A (user 1)
```

into

```
D (user 1) <-- master     G (user 2, original/refs/heads/master)
|                         |
C (user 1)                F (user 2)                E (user 1) <-- branch 1
|                         |                         |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|
B (user 1)
|
A (user 1)
```

So the question is, how can I get rid of F and G altogether? `original/refs/heads/master` does not appear to be a branch, but I am also not entirely sure what it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved with:

```
git update-ref -d refs/original/refs/heads/master
```